# Reading in a .csv file with null values in date field

Tags: sas

I am reading in a .csv file in SAS where some of the fields are populated in the main by null values `.` and a handful are populated by 5 digit SAS dates. I need SAS to recognise the field as a date field (or at the very least a numeric field), instead of reading it in as text as it is is doing at the minute.

A simplified version of my code is as so:

```
data test;
informat mydate date9.;
infile myfile dsd dlm ',' missover;
input
myfirstval
mydate
;
run;
```

With this code all values are read in as `.` and the field data type is text. Can anyone tell me what I need to change in the above code to get the output I need?

Thanks

Comment: Your example is a data step. In a data step it will never do other than what you programmed. Are you talking about the behavior of so some type of utility like PROC IMPORT that must guess about the data structure when reading a CSV file?

Comment: i am reading it in using an infile statement in a datastep.

Comment: What do you mean by '5 digit SAS dates'?  Are you talking about integer values that represent the number of days since 1/1/1960?  If so then read them as a number and attach a `FORMAT` like DATE9. to them instead of an `INFORMAT`.

Comment: i'm not sure you understand my question. a 'SAS date' always refers to the number of days since 1960. the issue i have is as many values are set to null in the file being read in, SAS interprets the field as text rather than a numeric field, even if you apply an informat during the import process. all none null values are represented by a null value anyway for some reason. applying a format to try and change the content of a field in an infile if you are getting a problem earlier in the chain than where the format is applied is shutting the stable door after the horse has already bolted.

Comment: Can you add some sample data that demonstrates the issue you are having?

Answer (score 0):

If you write a data step to read a CSV file SAS will create the variable as the data type that you specify. If you tell it that MYDATE is a number it will NOT convert it to a character variable.

```
data test;
   infile cards dsd dlm=',' TRUNCOVER ;
   length myfirstval 8 mydate 8 mythirdval 8;
   input myfirstval mydate mythirdval;
   format mydate date9.;
cards;
1,1234,5
2,.,6
;
```

Note that the data step compiler will define the type of the variable at the first chance that it can. For example if the first reference is in a statement like `IF MYDATE='.' ...` then `MYDATE` will be defined as character length one to match the type of the value that it is being compared to. That is why it is best to start with a `LENGTH` or `ATTRIB` statement to clearly define your variables.